# Disable LAN Interface duirng boot

Tags: pi-3, usb, ethernet, raspbian-buster, systemd-startup

Is there any option to disable LAN and USB interfaces during boot.
I found options to disable the interfaces using the Following command.

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/buspower > /dev/null
```

But I need it to be disabled during boot and enable manually once Pi turns ON.

Comment: "*I need it to be disabled during boot and enable once Pi turns ON.*" What's the difference between "during boot" and "once Pi turns ON"? They're same.

Comment: I want to enable it manually after Pi turns ON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Raspbian, network interfaces are managed with **dhcpcd** by default. If you want to start interfaces manually then you should first disable its service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl reboot
```

This ensures that the interface isn't started on boot first and then disabled by a job. You can start an interface with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo dhcpcd -w eth0
eth0: waiting for carrier
eth0: carrier acquired
DUID 00:01:00:01:25:1e:c1:bd:dc:a6:32:01:db:ed
eth0: IAID 32:01:db:ec
eth0: adding address fe80::77c0:a4bd:e655:5427
eth0: rebinding lease of 192.168.50.137
eth0: probing address 192.168.50.137/24
eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
eth0: leased 192.168.50.137 for 3600 seconds
eth0: adding route to 192.168.50.0/24
eth0: adding default route via 192.168.50.1
forked to background, child pid 676
```

For the command to manage the USB interfaces you should create a systemd Unit file:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit disable-usb.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements:

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable USB interfaces
After=sysinit.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/buspower'
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c 'echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/buspower'

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

Enable the new service and monitor it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable --now disable-usb.service
rpi ~$ systemctl status disable-usb.service
```

The service will run on boot up and disable the USB interfaces. You can enable/disable them manually with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl stop disable-usb.service
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl start disable-usb.service
```

Comment: According to your answer in need to run ```sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd.service``` and reboot the Pi. But, I don't know wham the Pi will restart. I need the interface to be disabled whenever Pi reboots.

Comment: This is exactly what `sudo systemctl disable ...` do. It prevent services to start on boot. You only have to do it one time. Then the service will never start automatically, no matter when the RasPi reboots. Independent from that you can always manual `sudo systemctl start ...` and `sudo systemctl stop ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable an interface by running `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` and also enable that by `sudo ifconfig eth0 up`.

If you concern that it would be disabled after startup/booting up, you have to make a special service and enable startup that.
Also you can add the command to crontab by:

```
crontab -e
```

And put this line there:

```
@reboot ifconfig eth0 down
```

More information about [Run programs/commands On Your Raspberry Pi At Startup](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/).

---

As the body of the question, you also need to disable USB interface like the command you have added. Just put that command to your service which you have created for `eth0` or `crontab`.