# rfkill: cannot open /dev/rfkill: Permission denied

Tags: networking

I tried the following [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108050/109982) to disable networking, but an error is thrown when I log in.

```
systemctl disable dhcpcd
```

> rfkill: cannot open /dev/rfkill: Permission denied

I also disabled Bluetooth and Wi-Fi by adding `dtoverlay=disable-bt` and `dtoverlay=disable-wifi` to `/boot/config.txt`.

Would you happen to know how to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out!

The issue is triggered by `/etc/profile.d/wifi-check.sh`.

Here is a fix:

```
sudo sed -i '2i\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ exit 0' /etc/profile.d/wifi-check.sh
```

Comment: Welcome to RPi SE, and congratulations on solving your problem!

Comment: It works on RPi4 as well!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command `rfkill list all`

The output should be:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

And then `rfkill unblock all`

Comment: the answer is a mess... please format the printout as code